# Determinable randomness, indeterminable certainty?

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

It is my understanding that there are two types of random number generation used in computer science. True random number generators that use principles of a physical property to determine their generation and pseudo random generators that use algorithms based upon mathematics such as chaos theory. True random number generators use a proposed indeterminate properties of the physical world because of the principle of uncertainty and pseudo random number generators employ chaos theory which are non linear deterministic equations whose outcomes are sensitive to initial conditions however they are deterministic and with the same initial conditions the outcome will be the same. My question is the principle in true random numbers generators and the principle of using chaos theory in pseudo random number generators the sane, as both principles use a deterministic factor the schrodinger equation in true random number generators and deterministic equations of chaos in pseudo random number generator,so what's the difference? Is randomness actually certainty? or vice versa?

Comment: Not all pseudorandom number generators rely on chaos theory. Anyway, what one wants in practice is a sequence that satisfies a list of conditions that truly random numbers would satisfy. If a pseudorandom sequence is, in some precise sense, indistinguishable from a truly random sequence, that's good enough.

Comment: Is it possible that the sequence of the birth of elementary particles in the universe was random over time or would there have been a pattern in the numbers over time, such as in a geometric progression or some other sequence? or is it impossible to count elementary particles and therefore have their presence in the universe expressed with a definite number? Sorry if its of topic but it just occurred to me.

Comment: Utterly off-topic, Bobs, and unlikely to attract any interest, much leas an answer, here.

Comment: No worries, what do you propose would make up the content of the list of conditions that a sequence would have  to satisfy in order for it to be deemed a random sequence, and how is indistinguishment a grey area, surely either a sequence is random or there is a pattern to the sequence? I am a layman, after all, but I am interested in physics and math.

Comment: I'll point you to Seminumerical Algorithms, Volume 2 of Knuth's The Art Of Computer Programming, for a discussion of what makes random. It's more comlicated than you might think.

Comment: Thank for your comments and I'll take a look at your suggested reading. It's been a pleasure :-)